# Not found "Create Add new " option in the Current Employer field if the org name typing

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, extension, autocomplete

We're already apply " Access API Permission " to anonymous user for creating Add New option organization to the current employer field but still not works. Civicrm-4.7. And added public automcomplete ext. to the current employer field. I go through the documentation https://github.com/TechToThePeople/publicautocomplete and added code in the civicrm.setting.php[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> If you want to force the user to submit only a value from the list (or
>   leave to leave it blank), thereby **preventing the user from creating
>   new organization records**, set the require_match config option to TRUE
>   (it defaults to FALSE):
>
> ```
> global $civicrm_setting;
> $civicrm_setting['eu.tttp.publicautocomplete']['require_match'] = TRUE;
> ```

This means, if you want to **allow the user to create new organization records,** you would omit this line, or set it to `FALSE`.

Also note: If you omit the line or set it to FALSE, you won't actually see a "Create New" option; you'll just be able to type in the name of an organization that's not in the list of options.

EDIT:

Regarding the potential for typos and duplicates, that will always exist any time you allow the user to enter a new organization name. CiviCRM will  follow the unattended dedupe rule for organizations when deciding whether to use an existing org or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As we understand it, this default is an either-or. Either it is set to FALSE, i.e. allows user to input anything into the field, including misspellings (?)

-or-

user may choose from a restricted list (group) "submit only a value from the list (or leave to leave it blank), " i.e. forced to leave.

We would want it as a conditional. If the user cannot locate their employer, then they have option to "create new" organization (and create the ensuing relationship in civi) H

Comment: This looks like a follow-up to my answer. If so, it's better as a comment to that answer than as a new answer. Please see my edit there about typos and dedupe rules.

Comment: We're getting the message we need "50 reputation" to add comment above (?) re : duplicates can you clarify what is meant by "unattended" vs. "unsuperivsed" dedupe rule for orgs. right now, the extension appears to be working yet it creating a new org each time we select the correct Employer. Tried adding a new unsupervised rule based solely on name not working tho. H

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/spidersilk/understanding-civicrm-dedupe-rules